# Pagination codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

**pagination is working but i dont know Why its showing only one data per page??** and i hv 20 data in my db and i can see only 6 data in 6pages :(

**This is my controller**

```
function view($page=0){
                $config = array();
                $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/view_expenses/view";
                $config["total_rows"] = $this->emp_expenses_model->getTotalExpensesCount();
                $config["per_page"] =1;
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                $this->data["results"] = $this->emp_expenses_model->getExpenses($config["per_page"], $page);
                $this->data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                $this->data['title'] = 'Payroll System';
                $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
                $this->load->view('view_expenses', $this->data);

    }
```

**This is my model**

```
function getTotalExpensesCount() {
            return $this->db->count_all("emp_expenses");
        }
      function getExpenses($limit, $start) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            $qry= $this->db->get("emp_expenses");
        return $qry->result();
         }
```

**Any help thanks in advance :D**

Comment: Initialize $page = 1 not 0.

Comment: checked its still showing all datas in all page.I mean for one page its showing one data.If i have 9data its showing but its taking 9 pages.what im trying is to show at least 3data per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function view(){
    $config                 = array();
    $config["base_url"]     = base_url() . "index.php/view_expenses/view/".$this->uri->segment(3);
    $config["total_rows"]   = $this->emp_expenses_model->getTotalExpensesCount();
    $config["per_page"]     = 5;
    $config['uri_segment']  = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->data["results"]  = $this->emp_expenses_model->getExpenses($config["per_page"], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data["links"]    = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->data['title']    = 'Payroll System';
    $this->data['message']  = $this->session->flashdata('message');
    $this->load->view('view_expenses', $this->data);

}

function getExpenses($limit, $start = 0) {
    $qry= $this->db->get("emp_expenses", $limit, $start);
    return $qry->result();
}
```

`$config["per_page"]     = 5;` means that you want to show 5 data per page, `$config['uri_segment']  = 3;` says what segment will hold the offset which you will be using in your query. `$config["total_rows"]` defines the total no. of rows in your table. `$config["base_url"]` defines the url the pagination will hold.
The data you are showing in your view is no way related to the pagination. Check your query and the offset you are getting. E.g. place `echo $this->db->last_qeury();die;` in `function getExpenses()` just before return statement.

Comment: Thanks niloy for explaining these things... but what does this mean $start=o?

Comment: For the first time when there is no offset that is no `uri->segment(3)` it will be 0 by default. Is it working?

Comment: dude its working now :) i jst changed few things in view and changed per pag=10

Comment: your answered nt helped but ur explanation did :D

Comment: Am not sure what situation made you code the following :
`$config["base_url"]     = base_url() . "index.php/view_expenses/view/".$this->uri->segment(3);`
But the following worked for me good :
`$config["base_url"]     = base_url() . "index.php/view_expenses/view/";`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `uri segment` like

```
$config["uri_segment"] = $last_seg_no;
```

Here `$last_seg_no` will be the last segment where you can find the page number.And need to pass the `per page param` also like

```
$config["per_page"] = 1;//As per your case
```

Answer (score 1):

"dont know Why its showing only one data per page??" because of `$config["per_page"] =1;`.

Add the following,

`$config['uri_segment'] = 3; // change based on ur url`

Change the value from `$config["per_page"] =1;` to `$config["per_page"] =3;` to display 3 data per page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;

$config["per_page"] = 3;
```

Modifiy modal function like this

```
function getTotalExpensesCount() {
   $this->db->select("count(*) as CNT"); 
   $qry = $this->db->get("emp_expenses");
   $result2 = $qry->row()->CNT;
   return $result2;
}
```

Comment: no its only changing number of links...see im restricting data in model page where i use limit.
in view page i tried this
var_dump($results);die('asd');
and its showing one data how to increase that

Comment: What are you getting for $config["total_rows"]?

Comment: der im geting null value.but their i want to count how many rows i have in my table.
these two lines where im restricting values,but if i change per_page value its only changing the links but not showing more datas in one page
$config["per_page"] =2;
$this->data["results"] = $this->emp_expenses_model->getExpenses($config["per_page"], $page);

Comment: and whenever i add new data its only increase another link for that :(

Answer (score 1):

i have faced this same problem. Now it solved by changing this

```
$config['uri_segment']
```